# Can you trace I/O activity for a process on MacOS?

Tags: macos, io, trace, iokit, darwin

Does MacOS have a utility/command for tracing I/O activity (e.g. via IOKit) for a process for debugging purposes?

There exists tools for network, syscall, etc. activity but I can't find any information for how to find which devices a specific process is currently using, for example. Is this even possible with Darwin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly *tracing*, but you can view an IOKit service object's user clients (represented by `IOUserClient` objects) using `ioreg` (CLI) or IORegistryExplorer.app (GUI, from Xcode Additional Tools package) or IOJones.app (open source GUI). This will tell you which processes are connected to an `IOService` at a given time, although it may be difficult to see short-lived connections.

I'm not aware of a pre-made tracing tool, but it should be possible to write your own `dtrace` script which does this. Note that IOKit calls are not syscalls but use Mach messaging, so your best bet is probably to trace the kernel equivalents of the various `IOConnectCall*()` family of functions and similar. I've been meaning to write something like this myself but thus far haven't had a chance to do so. ([I did update](https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit/commits/master/Scripts/Mac/Tracing/dtruss) [`dtruss`](https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit/tree/master/Scripts/Mac/Tracing) to be a lot more useful on macOS than the version that ships with the OS a while back but `dtruss` doesn't help with IOKit unfortunately.)

Comment: That's exactly the information I needed, thank you :)